# Can I create multiple css class name as one statement?

Tags: sass

I'm just creating `.scss` file for styled my website. In this `.scss` will be using in 4 differences web page with the not same class name. Here is my sample.

```
.my-login {
  .my-login__aside {
    width: 605px;
    padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    .my-login__logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is "Can I duplicate my current `.scss` to other names without creating more statement ?".

I want the result like this when `webpack` compile my `.scss` file.

```
.my-login {
  .my-login__aside {
    width: 605px;
    padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    .my-login__logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
}

.my-register {
  .my-register__aside {
    width: 605px;
    padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    .my-register__logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
}

.my-verify {
  .my-verify__aside {
    width: 605px;
    padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    .my-verify__logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
}

.my-reset {
  .my-reset__aside {
    width: 605px;
    padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    .my-reset__logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can do it with a loop function.

```
$pages: login register verify reset;
@each $page in $pages {
  .my-#{$page} {
    .my-#{$page}__aside {
      width: 605px;
      padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

      .my-#{$page}__logo {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
      }
    }
  }
}
```